# Can WAMP and EasyPHP live together and why is that true?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, wamp, easyphp

I've been using WAMP to work with PHP. These days after joining PHP mailing list from php.org, I want to have a try on EasyPHP. Though I'm not confident to get on alone with EasyPHP :)

So my question is can WAMP and EasyPHP be installed the same time on Windows7 (or Ubuntu OS)?

Comment: I don't see why not.  You could probably even run Windows in a VM and give the WAMP a different port, and run both servers at once.

Comment: @bdares I just worry the conflicts may occur - Apache/MySQL settings of WAMP would override ones of EasyPHP and vice versa. What do you think?

Comment: Install them to different folders.  You're even installing them on different OSes, so the class paths and such will be different.  They happen to share the same physical machine, which means that if they are grabbing for the same ports then you'll have a conflict, but otherwise there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I've tried to install EasyPHP and see that their Apache use port 8888 which is not conflicted with WAMP (while WAMP default to use 80 often conflicted with IIS). EasyPHP seems to be smarter ^_^ Just don't like their icon/logo very much though

Comment: @bdares Would you put your answer into an SO asnwer so that I can pick it up as accepted?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Both are LAMP Stacks. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Blake They are just AMP stack not LAMP stakc I guess. I just want to try them both on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.  You might take a performance hit from running both OSes at once (which you can do using a VM), but as long as you don't try to make them share resources (e.g. ports and config files), they won't even know the other exists.

Comment: I notice that WAMP and EasyPHP share the same MySQL databases. I'm not sure if they share the same Apache and/or PHP installation? What do you think?